# Prevent ondestroyview to be called for Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have a scenerio in which I am using Fragment with viewpager. The viewpager is having nested fragments with each fragment having a listview. I am using FragmentStatePagerAdapter and have given setOffscreenPageLimit as the size of arraylist. Now when i switch from this fragment to another fragment, all the fragments of viewpager are destroyed. Is there any way to prevent the fragments to be destroyed.

---

Comment: If you have a limited number of pages, check [ViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(int limit)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOffscreenPageLimit%28int%29). If you're using a FragmentPagerAdapter, check [FragmentPagerAdapter.saveState()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerAdapter.html#saveState%28%29).

Comment: f i give setOffscreenPageLimit then previous fragments get destroyed and recreated again. I do not want this. Also if i navigate from this main fragment to other fragment, then all the fragments in the stack gets destroyed. I want to retain all the fragments. setRetainInstance do not work with nested fragments. How do I achieve this?